# Why am I getting "java.net.SocketExcpecption: Connection reset"?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, java-io

I'm trying to write a tcp client and server program. The server's working just fine, it's opening the socket normally, but when I run the client program, i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at server.Client.main(Client.java:22)
```

Can anyone tell me how I fix it? Thanks in advance

Here is my client code

```
public class Client {

private final static String serverIP = "192.168.56.1";
private final static int serverPort = 50000;
private final static String fileOutput ="D:\\Julian\\Kancolle.7z";

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Socket sock = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
    byte[] byte_arr = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(byte_arr, 0, byte_arr.length);
    bos.write(byte_arr, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

and server code

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

private final static int serverPort = 50000;                        // reserves port
private final static String fileInput = "D:\\Julian\\Kancolle";     // destination

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    int bytesRead; // buffer variable

    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
    File myFile = new File(fileInput);
    while (true) {
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();

      InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer

      while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
      {
          output.write(buffer,  0,  bytesRead);;
      }
      output.close();
      servsock.close();
    }
}

public static void start(){
    Server upd = new Server();  
    Thread tupd = new Thread(upd);  
    tupd.start(); 
}

@Override
public void run() {

}
}
```

Comment: This code does not produce this exception, unless you killed the server process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense. Both sides are reading from the socket and copying to a `FileOutputStream`. Nobody is sending anything over the socket. So what should really be happening is a mutual-read deadlock after the first connection.

You are also incorrectly closing the `ServerSocket` inside the `accept()` loop. So your server will get an undisclosed `SocketException: socket closed` when trying to accept the second connection, exit, the OS will close the leaked accepted socket, and propagate a FIN or a reset to the peer, depending on the platform.